# How to get text within quotes and store in a list using tcl commands

Tags: tcl

I would like to get text within quotes into a list. It might be single or double qoutes.

ex_string :

```
( "abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-  'ds" | 'aac'(!)     = '--  ok' : text= 'abc')
```

And i want the list to be like

```
{abc_|a'b} {bda} {bb-  'ds} {aac} {-- ok} {abc}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that a regular expression can solve. However, you've got to post-process the results (`lmap` and `string cat` are perfect for the task in this case):

```
set str {( "abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-  'ds" | 'aac'(!)     = '--  ok' : text= 'abc')}
set items [lmap {a b c} [regexp -all -inline {"([^\"]*)"|'([^\']*)'} $str] {
    string cat $b $c
}]
puts "found: $items"
# found: abc_|a'b bda {bb-  'ds} aac {--  ok} abc
```

There's no braces around items that don't need it. I'd expect you to be OK with that usually…

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
% set a {( "abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-'ds" | 'aac'(!) = '--ok')}
( "abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-'ds" | 'aac'(!) = '--ok')
% set b [string trim $a {() }]
"abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-'ds" | 'aac'(!) = '--ok'
% set c [string map {{ | } { } { = } { } {(!)} {}} $b]
"abc_|a'b" 'bda' "bb-'ds" 'aac' '--ok'
% concat {*}[lmap item $c {format "{%s}" [string trim $item {"'}]}]
{abc_|a'b} {bda} {bb-'ds} {aac} {--ok}
```

I'll explain later if necessary.

Documentation:
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Sorry @Peter Lewerin i just edited this post. it actually shouldn't break white_spaces, and also shouldn't grab text which is not in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Donal Fellows' answer, but using a non-greedy regular expression:

```
set str {( "abc_|a'b" | 'bda' | "bb-  'ds" | 'aac'(!)     = '--  ok' : text= 'abc')}
set items [lmap {- - s} [regexp -all -inline {(['"])(.*?)\1} $str] {set s}]
puts "found: $items"
# found: abc_|a'b bda {bb-  'ds} aac {--  ok} abc
```